# How to iterate over a list of pairs that fit in gaps in a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have an input list, say:

```
L = [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]
```

I want to iterate over sorted pairs so that each end of the pair fits between two different values in `L`. In this case an acceptable created list of pairs would be:

```
[(0.5, 1.2), (0.5, 1.4), (0.5, 2.1), (0.5, 2.6), (1.1, 1.4), (1.1, 2.1), (1.1, 2.6), (1.4, 2.1), (1.4, 2.6), (2.1, 2.6)]
```

The first element in a pair is allowed to be less than the smallest value in L and the second element in a pair can be larger than the largest value in L as in the example.

I don't mind what the exact values in the pairs are as long as they are not the same as any value in `L`.

How can you do this? I would like to iterate over this list of pairs rather than compute the full list and store it.

Comment: Can you add the expected output for this example?

Comment: @trincot I clarified that an example output is given.

Comment: Are the sorted pairs the *output*, not the input?

Comment: @trincot The pairs are the output that I would like to iterate over.

Comment: I don't understand. Output is output -- if you still need to iterate over it, then it is not the output? Where do the values 0.5 and 1.2 come from, if they are really  output? You want to generate numbers randomly?

Comment: @trincot Sorry. I mean I want to iterate over those sorted pairs given the input list. There is no output in that sense.

Comment: So you basically just don't want any of the tuple members to be equal to any item in L? (0.5, 2.6) does not fit "between" your example items in the list.

Comment: @sm There was an additional rule that "The first element in a pair is allowed to be less than the smallest value in L and the second element in a pair can be larger than the largest value in L as in the example." I don't want (1.4, 1.41) for example.

Comment: So what does "so that each end of the pair fits between two different values in L" mean here? Aren't those rules contradictory? Unless i'm interpreting that phrase wrong

Comment: So what about generating one value for each interval (by taking the middle) and add at both ends an extra value that is outside the range. Then this boils down to finding all sorted pairs from that set, right? So you have two phases. Which phase is the problem?

Comment: @Alex (1.4, 1.41) is not allowed as they both fit between the same pair of values in L. (1.4, 2.1) would be allowed as 1.4 and 2.1 fit between two different consecutive pairs in L.

Comment: @trincot that sounds like it could work.

Comment: So is your question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem breaks down in two separate problems:

- Create a list with  + 1 values, where the outer two values are outside of the input range (one less than the first, one more than the last), and the inner values are the averages of each consecutive pair in the input.
- Generate all possible (sorted) pairs from a list of values. This can be done with `itertools.combinations`.

Code:

```
from itertools import combinations 

def mids(lst):
    return lst and [lst[0]-1] + [sum(p)/2 for p in zip(lst, lst[1:])] + [lst[-1]+1]

lst = [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]
for pair in combinations(mids(lst), 2):
    print(pair)
```

Comment: for the 1st part, finding the average, it could be also done with [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) if python >= 3.10, `map(statistics.mean, itertools.pairwise(lst))` and eventually with an extra import for [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

Comment: @cards Please add an answer!

Comment: @Simd I think there are enough (and good!) answers:) Just edit `def mids(lst): return lst and [lst[0]-1] + list(map(statistics.mean, pairwise(lst))) + [lst[-1]+1]` assuming also `from itertools import pairwise` & `import statistics`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Python using the `itertools` module which provides various functions that work on iterators to produce complex iterators. Here, `itertools.combinations` can be used to generate pairs from a list and then adjusting these pairs slightly to ensure none of the values are the same as any in the input list.

For generating the adjusted pairs a simple generator function can be used as below ,

```
import itertools

def generate_pairs(L):
    L = sorted(L)
    L.insert(0, L[0]-1)  # Add a smaller value at the beginning
    L.append(L[-1]+1)    # Add a larger value at the end
    
    for pair in itertools.combinations(L, 2):
        # Adjust pair to ensure neither value is the same as any in the original list
        adjusted_pair = (pair[0]+0.1, pair[1]-0.1)
        yield adjusted_pair

L = [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]

for pair in generate_pairs(L):
    print(pair)
```

Here, pairs are adjusted by adding 0.1 to the first value and subtracting 0.1 from the second value. You can change this value depending on your needs just ensure that after adjustment, the pairs still fit in between the two different values in the original list.

I assume that the original list is sorted and if its not then you can add a line of code to sort it before generating the pairs.

Comment: Thank you! Can the 0.1 be made dynamic so I don't need to know the size of the gaps in advance?

Comment: @Simd you can get the average of them

Comment: do something like `diff = min(L[i+1] - L[i] for i in range(len(L)-1)) / 2` (i.e. half of the smallest difference between two items. Then that can safely be used in place of 0.1

Comment: Yes, In that case you can calculate the difference between the two numbers in the pair and use a small fraction of that difference to adjust the pair. This way, the adjustment will be dynamic and based on the gap between the numbers.

Comment: import itertools

def generate_pairs(L):
    L = sorted(L)
    L.insert(0, L[0]-1)  # Add a smaller value at the beginning
    L.append(L[-1]+1)    # Add a larger value at the end
    
    for pair in itertools.combinations(L, 2):
        # Adjust pair to ensure neither value is the same as any in the original list
        gap = pair[1] - pair[0]
        adjusted_pair = (pair[0] + gap * 0.1, pair[1] - gap * 0.1)
        yield adjusted_pair

L = [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]

for pair in generate_pairs(L):
    print(pair)


@Simd

Comment: @Developer consider `L = [1000, 1001, 1999, 2000]`. If `pair == (1000, 2000)`, then `adjusted_pair == (1100, 1900)` which wouldn't be valid.

Comment: @slothrop Ah, I see the issue you are referring. Yes so when the gaps between original values are different in size. We can use a strategy where we ensure the adjusted values are exactly halfway between the original values. That way, we know for sure that they wont  be the same as any original value and that they will still be within the gaps between original values.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify strict rules for the selection of the intermediate numbers and your arbitrary values and the expected output suggest that there is a gap of at lest 0.2 between values in L.  So, if any intermediate value is allowed with a resolution of 0.1, your iterator could be expressed like this:

```
L = [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]

iL  = ( (a-0.1,b+0.1) for i,a in enumerate(L) for b in L[i:] )
```

output:

```
for a,b in iL:
    print((round(a,2),round(b,2)),[n for n in L if a<n<b])

# pair     parts of L covered
(0.9, 1.1) [1]
(0.9, 1.4) [1, 1.3]
(0.9, 2.1) [1, 1.3, 2]
(0.9, 2.6) [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]
(1.2, 1.4) [1.3]
(1.2, 2.1) [1.3, 2]
(1.2, 2.6) [1.3, 2, 2.5]
(1.9, 2.1) [2]
(1.9, 2.6) [2, 2.5]
(2.4, 2.6) [2.5]
```

In order to make this a bit more generic, you could compute the increment based on the smallest difference before iterating:

```
L = [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]

inc = min(L[0],*(b-a for a,b in zip(L,L[1:]))) / 2 

iL  = ( (a-inc,b+inc) for i,a in enumerate(L) for b in L[i:] )
```

output:

```
for a,b in iL:
    print((round(a,2),round(b,2)),[n for n in L if a<n<b])

# pair       parts of L covered
(0.85, 1.15) [1]
(0.85, 1.45) [1, 1.3]
(0.85, 2.15) [1, 1.3, 2]
(0.85, 2.65) [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]
(1.15, 1.45) [1.3]
(1.15, 2.15) [1.3, 2]
(1.15, 2.65) [1.3, 2, 2.5]
(1.85, 2.15) [2]
(1.85, 2.65) [2, 2.5]
(2.35, 2.65) [2.5]
```

Comment: Your more generic method works really well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## First Approach

I have two approaches. The first involves finding the mid points, which others have already presented.

## Second Approach

In the second approach, I will first find all the differences between pairs of numbers. So for

```py
L = [1, 1.3, 2, 2.5]
```

The differences are 0.3, 0.7, 0.5. The smallest difference is 0.3. To ensure of no collision with the input, I take this smallest difference and divided by 2 to come up with 0.15, which I call the delta. From there, for each element, I just calculate and return (element - delta, element + delta).

```py
def brackets(seq):
    # Asume seq not sorted
    seq = sorted(seq)
    
    # Calculate delta: half of the smallest difference
    # between the pairs of input
    list1 = iter(seq)
    list2 = iter(seq)
    next(list2)
    delta = min(b - a for a, b in zip(list1, list2)) / 2.0

    out = [
        (element - delta, element + delta)
        for element in seq
    ]
    return out
```

Sample run:

```py
>>> brackets([1, 1.3, 2, 2.5])
[(0.85, 1.15), (1.15, 1.4500000000000002), (1.85, 2.15), (2.35, 2.65)]
```